# module 'sklearn.feature_extraction.image' has no attribute 'extract_patches'

Tags: python

for the code i have no idea about how to extract_patches with 3 positional

```
for filei in phases[phase]:
    fname=files[filei] 
    
    print(fname)
    classid=[idx for idx in range(len(class_names)) if class_names[idx] in fname][0]
    totals[classid]+=1

    io=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(fname),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    interp_method=PIL.Image.BICUBIC


    io = cv2.resize(io,(0,0),fx=resize,fy=resize, interpolation=interp_method) #resize it as specified above
    io = np.pad(io, [(mirror_pad_size, mirror_pad_size), (mirror_pad_size, mirror_pad_size), (0, 0)], mode="reflect")

    #convert input image into overlapping tiles, size is ntiler x ntilec x 1 x patch_size x patch_size x3
    io_arr_out=sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches(io,(patch_size,patch_size,3),stride_size)
   

    #resize it into a ntile x patch_size x patch_size x 3
    io_arr_out=io_arr_out.reshape(-1,patch_size,patch_size,3)



    storage["imgs"].append(io_arr_out)
    storage["labels"].append([classid for x in range(io_arr_out.shape[0])]) #add the filename to the storage array
    storage["filenames"].append([fname for x in range(io_arr_out.shape[0])]) #add the filename to the storage array
```

Comment: Is your question why you get the error message mentioned in the title?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patchify` instead:

```
from patchify import patchify
io_arr_out = patchify(io, (patch_size,patch_size,3), step = stride_size )
```